# Error in Image Crop function in Jython

Tags: image, jython, crop, jes

Okay, so for an assignment I have to make a function `crop()` that will crop a picture in `test_crop()`. Here's the code.

```
def crop(pict, startX, startY, endX, endY):
 width = endX - startX + 1
 height = endY - startY + 1
 canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width, height)
 targetX = 100
 for sourceX in range(45,200):
  targetY = 100
  for sourceY in range(25,200):
    color = getColor(getPixel(pict, sourceX, sourceY))
    setColor(getPixel(canvas, targetX, targetY), color)
    targetY = targetY + 1
  targetX = targetX + 1
show(pict)
show(canvas)
return canvas

def test_crop():
 setMediaPath() 
 pict = makePicture("redMotorcycle.jpg")
 croppedPict = crop(pict, 100, 100, 700, getHeight(pict)/2)
 show(pict)
 show(croppedPict)
```

The error occurs on this piece of code:

```
setColor(getPixel(canvas, targetX, targetY), color)
```

It says `"Inappropriate argument (of correct type. An error occured attempting to pass an argument to a function."`

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with it? It is the same code from the textbook.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the exact error message?

Comment: Sure, it says:
"Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function."

Comment: What version of jython are you using?

Comment: JES (Jython Environment for Students)

Answer (score 0):

This works. I cannot work out why you are getting that error, it may be in how you are getting your values for `startX, startY, endX, endY` in
`def crop(pict, startX, startY, endX, endY):`

```
def crop(pict):
  width = getWidth(pict)
  height = getHeight(pict)
  canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width, height)
  targetX = 100
  for sourceX in range(45,200):
    targetY = 100
    for sourceY in range(25,200):
      color = getColor(getPixel(pict, sourceX, sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas, targetX, targetY),color)
      targetY = targetY + 1
    targetX = targetX + 1
  show(pict)
  show(canvas)
  return canvas
```

The original image:

[image: Original picture]

The cropped image:

[image: Cropped Picture]

This works, beyond this, you will need to provide more information about your code.